# How to create sequence when importing data using Toad for Oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence, toad

Hi I am trying to import data from a csv file
into a my Oracle Database using "Toad for Oracle"

I've created the corresponding columns,
but would like to create a PRIMARY KEY sequence
that corresponds with my data

How do you create sequences for imported data?

Comment: You create a `SEQUENCE` in the DB, and then refer to SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL which inserting data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a SEQUENCE with a TRIGGER:

```
create sequence seq_my_pk;

create table my_table (pk number not null primary key, value varchar2(30));

create or replace trigger tr_my_table_pk
  before insert on my_table
  for each row 
begin
  if :new.pk is null then
    :new.pk := seq_my_pk.nextval;
  end if;
end;
```

This will set the PK upon insertion if it was not provided in the INSERT statement.

If you're already on 12c, you can use the new `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` feature instead.

Comment: `Trigger` is good. But when it is large volume of data, `Sequence` would be better isnt it?

Comment: @OracleUser For large volumes of data / recurring imports, I'd use a separate staging table where every column is defined as VARCHAR2(4000). I'd then import the csv data into that staging table and transfer it to the target table with an INSERT ... SELECT, possibly including TO_NUMBER() / TO_DATE() transformations where necessary. This makes debugging erroneous input data much easier, since you can run ad-hoc queries against your staging table. And yes, in that case it would make more sense to include the sequence in the INSERT statement instead of using a trigger.